# sending xml data using post request

Tags: python, xml, post

http://api.shipstation.com/Order-Resource.ashx

Above URL is shipstation API document for fetching order,creating orders,updating and deleting.

I want to use create order API which is POST request ,where order data entries are sent to shipstation using xml.

My question is how i can send xml data to shipstation using POST request using Python?

Since iam not able to post entire code on this page ,so please refer this URL to see post request for creating order-

http://api.shipstation.com/Order-Resource.ashx

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you should try like this

```
def frame_xml(AddressVerified,AmountPaid):
    xml_data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <entry xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/ metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="SS.WebData.Order" />
     <title />
     <author>
     <name />
     </author>
     <id />
     <content type="application/xml">
     <m:properties>
       <d:AddressVerified m:type="Edm.Byte">%s</d:AddressVerified>
       <d:AmountPaid m:type="Edm.Decimal">%s</d:AmountPaid>
     </m:properties>
    </content>
   </entry>"""%(AddressVerified,AmountPaid)
   return xml_data

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
xml_data = frame_xml('AddressVerified','AmountPaid')
print requests.post('https://data.shipstation.com/1.2/Orders', data=xml_data, headers=headers).text
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) module. Some examples you can find on quick-start page:

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
>>> print r.text
    ...
```

Or

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}

>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
    ...
```

See more here: [How can I send an xml body using requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509888/how-can-i-send-an-xml-body-using-requests-library)

Comment: shipstation API have headers too like
POST https://data.shipstation.com/1.2/Orders HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0;NetFx
Accept: application/atom+xml,application/xml
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Host: data.shipstation.com
Content-Length: 4213
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

so how to put header in above code?

Comment: requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=xml, headers=headers). See more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509888/how-can-i-send-an-xml-body-using-requests-library