# send an XML file to rest API using python requests

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying to send an XML file with a rest api POST. the api takes the xml and creates a new entitiy.

I am trying to open the file and then sending it through requests.

```
filename = 'test.xml'

response = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(open(filename).readlines()))
```

But getting the 503 (API not able to get the right input). My intention is to send this XML as it is to api.

If I don't do json.dumps, I get `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: It seems that I need to pass the file object and don't have to do read() or readlines().

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I send an xml body using requests library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509888/how-can-i-send-an-xml-body-using-requests-library)

Comment: Can you point us to the documentation for your API?

Comment: @Varun - If you have discovered an answer to your question, please share the details in an answer (which you may accept from yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API takes XML, not JSON. When you say, `data = json.dumps(...)`, you are passing JSON to your API. This is the reason for your first error message -- 503 (API not able to get the right input).

`requests.post()` takes ether a dictionary, a string, or a file-like object as its `data=` parameter. When you do `data = foo.readlines()`, you are passing in a list (which is neither a string nor a dictionary. This is the reason for your second error message -- "ValueError: too many values to unpack".

Without knowing your API, it is hard to guess what is correct. Having said that, try this:

```
filename = 'test.xml'
response = requests.post(api_url, data=open(filename).read())
```

Or, nearly equivalently, this:

```
filename = 'test.xml'
response = requests.post(api_url, data=open(filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, you are trying to convert the xml file into json data (using json.dumps()) directly and post it. I guess the API accepts JSON. Then first try to convert the xml file to a python dictionary / whatever data structure suits it. Then convert it into json.

Comment: OP does say that the API takes XML. Converting it to JSON seems contrary to that.

Comment: If it's the case, then no need for json.dumps, he just needs to load the xml file into a string and send it over.

Thanks for pointing it out.