# How do I send an XML ElementTree with Python Requests?

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, elementtree

I want to send an XML POST request using the Python 3 [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.

When I create my XML body as a plaintext string, I am able to [send XML bytes to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12510559/3357935) without any issues. However, if I send my request as an [`ElementTree.Element`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), the server responds with the error message "*Premature end of file*".

#### Writing XML as plaintext (works)

```
import requests

root = """<?xml version = '1.0'?>
          <Kronos_WFC version = '1.0'> </Kronos_WFC>"""
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
print(requests.post('http://localhost/wfc/XmlService', data=root, headers=headers)).text

# Output:
# <Kronos_WFC version="1.0" WFCVersion="6.3.13.362" TimeStamp="10/30/2017 12:19PM GMT-04:00"></Kronos_WFC>
```

#### Building XML with ElementTree (fails)

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import requests

root = ET.Element("Kronos_WFC", version="1.0")
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
print(requests.post('http://localhost/wfc/XmlService', data=root, headers=headers)).text

# Output:
# <Kronos_WFC>
#    <Response Status="Failure" ErrorCode="-1" Message="Premature end of file.">
#    </Response></Kronos_WFC>
```

When I tried printing my XML ElementTree to debug, I found that Python was interpreting it as an object, rather than as parsable text. I suspect that this may be the cause of the issue.

```
root = ET.Element("Kronos_WFC", version="1.0")
print(root)

# Output:
# <Element 'Kronos_WFC' at 0x013492D0>
```

Ideally I would like to build my XML POST request using `ElementTree.Element`, then send it to an API using Requests.

**How can I send an XML `ElementTree.Element` to a server using Python Requests?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ElementTree.tostring()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) to create a string representation of the xml.

```
requests.post(
    'http://localhost/wfc/XmlService', 
    data=ET.tostring(root), 
    headers=headers
)
```

Comment: You are right. The api is a little unintuitive. I would expect ElementTree to have some sort of `tostring` method. It does have a `write` method for writing to a file.