# Python, XML sending POST requests with format

Tags: python, xml, python-requests

I'm attempting to make a bot, although the post request requires to be in XML, I have no experience dealing with XML and I'd like your help.

The request payload looks a bit like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryyXmSIiVhzetQj7u9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Name"

asdafa
------WebKitFormBoundaryyXmSIiVhzetQj7u9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Description"


------WebKitFormBoundaryyXmSIiVhzetQj7u9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Genre"

All
------WebKitFormBoundaryyXmSIiVhzetQj7u9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="thumbnailImageFile"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

How would I replicate that in python?

I've tried simple things such as

```
create = s.post(url='https://www.url.com/', data=xml)
```

I've also tried having a header like {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'} and I've had no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I send an xml body using requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509888/how-can-i-send-an-xml-body-using-requests-library)

Comment: That's not XML.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you're trying to submit form data using the
`multipart/form-data` format.  You can do this with the `requests`
library by making use of the `files` parameter, which is documented in
the "[Post a multipart encoded
file](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)"
section of the documentation, which shows the following example:

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': ('report.csv', 'some,data,to,send\nanother,row,to,send\n')}
>>> result = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

This would result in the following data being sent to the server:

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=66702e4da1364ad181a6ef1437ed39ce

--66702e4da1364ad181a6ef1437ed39ce
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="report.csv"

some,data,to,send
another,row,to,send

--66702e4da1364ad181a6ef1437ed39ce--
```

As you can see, this is almost what you want, except it includes
erroneous `filename` parameters.  These will not be included if you
pass `None` as the filename.  To make it easier to send dictionaries
using this format, I wrote the following helper method:

```
def dict_to_multipart(d):                                                                 
    return {k: (None, v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

If we have data that looks like this:

```
data = {'Name': 'asdf', 'Genre': 'all'}
```

We can send it like this:

```
result = requests.post('https://requestbin.fullcontact.com/1oso55v1',
                       files=dict_to_multipart(data))
```

The data that gets sent to the webserver in this case looks like:

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=60eaef81347645b4b1e9a2f02634baca

--60eaef81347645b4b1e9a2f02634baca
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Genre"

all
--60eaef81347645b4b1e9a2f02634baca
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Name"

asdf
--60eaef81347645b4b1e9a2f02634baca--
```